# In Swift, why does .zero fill the entire window in this example?

Tags: ios, swift, cgrect

I'm following a tutorial on creating a WKWebView within a view controller and the WKWebView is instantiated with a CGRect value of .zero but the website opens to the entire size of the view controller when I run this code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController{

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        let myURL = URL.init(string: "https://www.apple.com")
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let myUrlRequest = URLRequest.init(url: myURL!)
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        view = webView
        webView.load(myUrlRequest)
    }
}
```

Doesn't .zero mean 0 for all values in CGRect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frame you provide is irrelevant. You are implementing `loadView` (not `viewDidLoad`). The web view `webview` you create in your code is the *main view* of this view controller. The frame of the main view of a view controller is *never* up to you; it is always resized by its parent view controller or, if it is the window's `rootViewController`, to fill the window.